# How to upload multiple files individually with additional data

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload, blueimp

I am using [blueimp's fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data). The data is sendable if I do not try to send an additional input on submit.

I am trying to upload files with a title following this pattern:

1. user clicks "select HHs" button to select files
2. After the files are selected and opened, user sees every file listed in rows with a "title" input box and a "submit" button.
3. User types in value for the "title" input and clicks the "submit" button to send to the backend.

However after step 3, I get a 403 error and a "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)" on the server side (django). Why am I getting this error message and how do I solve this issue?

[image: this is what my code looks like]
I've replaced data.formData with a simple object to test what I'm trying to accomplish below.

upload.js file:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  formData: {title: 'test'},
  dataType: 'json',
  ...
  add: function (e, data) {
    var convertElem =   $('<input type="submit"/>').click(function() {
      data.formData = {"title":"test"}; 
      data.submit();
    });
    ...
    data.context = $(outerElem)
  ...
  }
});
```

upload.html:

```
<button>Select</button>
<form id="fileupload" data-url="{% url 'file-upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
  <input id="fileupload-files" type="file" name="file" multiple>
</form>
```

Comment: it looks like you need to use Django Formssets  please go through the link below https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: the reason why you are getting 403 error because you are not passing the csrf_token in the form body https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: thank you, I realize the additional input I've submitted are not bound to the csrf_token.